# Where is the CPU Monitor screen for the galaxy note edge?

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-note

Does the galaxy note edge have a built-in tool/screen for monitoring CPU usage?

If so, how is it accessed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Settings > About Device > scroll down and tap on build number until you unlock dev options. Then hit back. Click on dev options and the built in CPU monitor should be in there. But that's just the overlay. Hope this helps. Otherwise, download a 3rd party one from the play store.

Comment: Thanks. is there something that displays a graphical plot like task manager?

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bigbro.ProcessProfiler This has graphs, might be what you are looking for.